# NLP classification training model

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am trying to train a model to classify tweets using opennlp. My question is should I perform tokenization, stop word removal etc on the tweets which I am using for training the model or should I use the tweet directly without performing the sanitization?

Comment: What your model is trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are training:

- If your algorithm is designed to recieve simple text and it performs all the simplification by itself before using the machine learning techniques on it you should provide pairs of the type
- Otherwise if you are just trianing a black box I would say that if your model is going to work on a certain type of features, in your case tokenized and stemmed word it should be trained on this type of data so provide